# Best way to secure data PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, administration

I'm building an app that will store some of our clients details, things like usernames / passwords, information that we need to remember and keep secure.

What's the best method for storing this information securely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an open-ended question with not a lot of detail to go on. I'd suggest reading Chris Shiflett's excellent "[Essential PHP Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600656X)" before you go any further. It's short, to the point and very practical.

There's also a reasonable amount of the advice available from the book's website too at http://phpsecurity.org/

Answer (score 1):

## Using a PHP framework for security

If you want to get PHP security setup quickly without doing a load of research, a PHP framework would be a good idea.

I am a fan of [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) but other options include [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.com) and [Zend](http://framework.zend.com).

Using a framework for security will mean you get a tried and tested method straight away, however there may be some time and effort needed to learn the framework.

A total [list of PHP frameworks can be found on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_application_frameworks).

Comment: Using a framework will not prevent you from making insecure applications. You DO need to know about security best practices. Frameworks are no substitution for secure coding. Not educating yourself about security because you use a framework is a very ignorant way of digging your own security hole.

Comment: Fair enough. A framework is not a silver bullet. However, the built-in security classes which can clean up your data and help you avoid many XSS exploits can be very useful to someone with little experience.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple actually. Set up a quick MySQL database, and a user table. In that user table, store the usernames in a column and a hashed version of the password in another column.

As added security, I like to generate a random 8 character string and store that as well in each row - I call that column the "Keycode". When the user signs in with a correct username / password, I store their authentication in session variables AS WELL as the matching "Keycode".

That way, the session authentication can not only look for the right username / password, but quickly query the db, and check to see if the "Keycode" stored in the session variable is the same as the keycode in the row.

It works well because not even the user knows their keycode.

Answer (score 0):

As far as passwords go you should store a hash of the password.  Whenever you authenticate the user, you hash their inputted password and compare the result with what you've stored.  This way you aren't storing the actual password.